# List equivalent in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am new in angular (TypeScript), I want to implement composition between two classes. How can i achieve that?

In c# if I have two classes like A and B then I implement composition like following

```
class A 
{
  int ID {get;set;}
  List<B> lstClassB {get;set;}
}

class B {
  int ID {get;set;}
}
```

How can I use this functionality in TypeScript like

```
export class A 
{
  ID :int;
  lstClassB :  ////what should I write here?
}

export class B {
  ID:int;
}
```

Comment: I changed your question slightly by replacing the word Inheritance with Composition and angular with TypeScript so that it makes more sense and better reflects what I believe you are actually asking.

Answer (score 9):

It will be:

```
export class A 
{
   ID :number;
   lstClassB : Array<B> ;
}
```

Comment: `int` is not a TypeScript type.

Comment: Ya...Thanks for pointing it out. Copy pasted from the question so didn't notice

Answer (score 4):

In Typescript you do `B[]` means type of B array

```js
export class A {
    ID: number;
    list: B[];
}
```

To use setter and getter:

```js
export class A {
   private _ID: number;
   set ID(value:number) {
       this._ID = value;
   }
   get ID():number {
       return this._ID;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `number` and `Array` (or `[]`) in your TypeScript definition:

```js
export class A 
{
  ID: number;
  lstClassB: Array<B>;
}
```

or

```js
export class A 
{
  ID: number;
  lstClassB: B[];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In TypeScript you can use either `Array<T>` or `T[]` to define an array of items.

```
export class A 
{
  ID :number;
  lstClassB : B[];
}
```

or

```
export class A 
{
  ID :number;
  lstClassB : Array<B>;
}
```

Also what you are describing in composition, not inheritance.

Comment: `int` is not a TypeScript type.

Comment: @Reactgular - that's what I get for copy/pasting without looking it over once more.

Answer (score 1):

In Typescript, Array types can be written in one of two ways:

1.Use the type of the elements followed by `[]` to denote an array of that element type. Ex:

```
export class A 
{
  ID :number;
  lstClassB : B[];
}
```

2. The second way uses a generic array type, `Array<elemType>`

   ```
   export class A 
     {
       ID :number;
       lstClassB : Array<B> ;
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It should be the same, you will define an array of type B

```
export class A 
{
  ID :number;
  lstClassB : Array<B> ;
}
```

Comment: `int` is not a TypeScript type.